# Can Marketo edit lead fields before sending them to Salesforce?

Tags: integration, marketo

Can Marketo edit lead fields before sending them to Salesforce?

So a new lead comes into Marketo with the phone number filled in as `+1347567(5467)`. Can we convert that to `3475675467` within Marketo before sending the data to SF?

Alternatively, can Salesforce edit that number as it comes in?

Answer (score 1):

You can handle in Salesforce through Workflow Rule where

> Evaluation Criteria: Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria
>
> Rule Criteria: Phone Number is not null.

**Workflow Action: Field Update Details**

Based on formula like this:

```
    SUBSTITUTE( 
      SUBSTITUTE( 
         SUBSTITUTE( MobilePhone , '+1','')
     ,')',''), 
   '(', '')
```

Comment: if my ans solves your purpose then select this, so that other members can find this useful.